# How to install NodeJs, NextJs in a using the terminal in a 32 Toshiba computer?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, next.js

I have been trying to install node, and nextjs in my 32 bit Toshiba computer. I am using Lubuntu and I don't if that's why. Please any help will truly appreciated!

This is the error I am having..

Error: download preflight failed for '18.17.1' (https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.17.1/node-v18.17.1-linux-x86.tar.xz)

when tried to install sudo n 18.17.1. And I currently have node v8.10.0

I have tried to install version 18.. in Lubuntu using sudo n 18.17.1. And I currently have node v8.10.0. But it's throwing this error

Error: download preflight failed for '18.17.1' (https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.17.1/node-v18.17.1-linux-x86.tar.xz)

I am expecting to upgrade to version 18... However, when I tried with the lower version to install nextjs using npm. Npm is not present.